# libperl.so error when starting nginx on pclinuxos

Tags: libraries, nginx, webserver

I have just installed pclinuxos on an old laptop and needed a webserver for a test environment. Decided to learn a new webserver so I have more options than just using Apache all the time and so went for nginx for the first time.

Installed fine, but when I type:

```
service nginx start
```

on the command line, I get:

```
Starting nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx: error while loading shared libraries:
libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                            [FAILED]
```

Some google search results on the error say I have to configure a file with the correct location of `libperl.so`.

My question has several parts:
1. How do I know if I even have `libperl.so` installed?
2. If I do, how do I locate it?
3. Where do I find the file I need to update the location in?
4. If I don't have it installed, how do I install it?

Just looking to get as far as nginx's equivalent of Apache's "It works" page. Whatever that is, I haven't seen it yet.
`